# Near-field diffraction model

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, diffraction, models

I want to calculate diffraction losses due to the presence of human blockages which are modeled as cylinders with random heights and diameters, what is appropriate method that can I use in case of near field? uniform theory of diffraction (UTD) model or Fresnel  diffraction?