# Near-field diffraction

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, diffraction, models

I want to calculate near field diffraction loss due to the presence human blockages which are  modeled as cylinders with random heights and diameters in indoor mm wave network

as mentioned in " [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_theory_of_diffraction#:~:text=In%20numerical%20analysis%2C%20the%20uniform,dimension%20at%20the%20same%20point"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_theory_of_diffraction#:%7E:text=In%20numerical%20analysis%2C%20the%20uniform,dimension%20at%20the%20same%20point%22).  The uniform theory of diffraction approximates near field electromagnetic fields as quasi optical and uses knife-edge diffraction to determine diffraction coefficients for each diffracting object-source combination

but I cannot understand how can i use knife-edge diffraction with cylindrical objects?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772745/2451

Comment: IEEE is your friend, see; for example, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4629305, and references and citations therein